# Hadoop GPG SerDe

Tags: encryption, hadoop, hive, gnupg

I am currently working on a Hadoop project that requires data encryption (because the data will be stored in S3).  While I primarily expect to access the data though Hive, it would be nice to be able to access it via Pig and any other MapReduce methods.

I know Hadoop has built-in support for compression codecs like gzip, snappy, etc...  Is there any support for encryption codecs as well (specifically, GPG)?  Has anyone written a GPG SerDe (or anything similar) that is publicly available?

Answer (score 0):

Last I knew Hadoop has no internal support for encryption whatsoever. Seems like you could overload the CompressionCodec with your GPG code, ala http://www.mail-archive.com/common-user@hadoop.apache.org/msg06229.html

Happy Hacking & let us know if you find a solution!